# web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount requires 3 arguments

Tags: web3js

I am using following code to unlock an account.

```
 web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(address, password);
```

But I get an error message:

> Error: Invalid Arguments length: expected: 3, given: 2

Comment: The error message seems pretty clear. Here's the documentation, which seems to agree: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-personal.html#unlockaccount.

Comment: Yeah but unlock duration used to be defaulted to 300. Why such a breaking change?

Comment: If you want to know why a change was made in a certain library, I would think you would need to ask the developers who work on that library.

Comment: Yeah, probably I no question was needed here. I was just little surprised by that. Thanks BTW :)

Answer (score 0):

try to add the duration

```
web3.eth.personal.unlockAccount(accts[2],password,0)
```

if you put 0 it will be unlocked untill the node is restarted